# Debug into a custom metrics function in Keras/Tensorflow (in Pycharm)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

I have created a simple *ConfusionMatrix* custom metric and am running into a problem in Tensor conversion.  It would speed up fixing if I could set a breakpoint. However breakpoints are not being respected by *PyCharm* .

Here is the code

```
def multiConfusion(expectsIn, actsIn):
  expects = tf.keras.backend.eval(expectsIn)  # Error occurs here
  acts = tf.keras.backend.eval(actsIn)
  classes = sorted(list(set(expects).union(set(acts))))
  
  from collections import defaultdict
  mx = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
  for e,a in list(zip(expects,acts)):
    mx[e][a] += 1
  hdr = "Exp/Act" + ''.join([ f'\t\t{lab}' for lab in classes])
  ll = '\n'.join([
                  '\t\t\t' + '\t\t'.join([ str(mx[e][a]) for k,a in list(mx[e].items())])
                  for e in classes
                 ])
  mat =  f"{hdr}\n{ll}"
  print(mat)
  return mat

def confusionMat(x,y,num_classes=NClasses):
      from tensorflow import math as tfmath
      cmat = None
      if NClasses == 2:
        cmat = binaryConfusion(x,y)
      else:
        cmat = multiConfusion(x,y) # Breakpoint set here but gets skipped
      print(repr(cmat))
      return cmat

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, 
              metrics=[confusionMat,"accuracy"])
```

[image]

Some thoughts I had on trying to re-enable the debugger:

- set single threaded mode

`tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)`

- set eager execution mode

`vgg_model.run_eagerly = True`

But still the breakpoint is not respected. Any thoughts?

**Update**  I have tested / updated / expanded the above code a fair bit. It does generate a confusion matrix properly

[image]

Debugging into the code works fine when called with a constant Tensorflow Tensor directly.

But nothing I can do will make the debugger activate when the code is invoked via the *metrics* machinery within the Tensorflow *model* training. (via *model.fit()*)

Comment: @bad_coder  Thx - i have now tried a number of different transformations (with or without keras):  debugging in the context of a TF training loop just does not want to happen.  The same code debugs without complaints when run just against a tensorflow tensor (but _not_ while training)

Answer (score 2):

For your breakpoints to be respected, add this line at the beginning:

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

It will make tensorflow run almost everything eagerly except for `tf.data` transformation pipeline.

Comment: that sounds v promising - thx!  Will upvote straightaway and check it out to see if actually resolves shortly

Comment: Does not seem to be doing the job: breakpoints still not respected. But i'll leave the upvote since your tip may well be useful for others/other cases